# How can I build and run Druid locally

Tags: docker, druid

My environment are below.

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports)
- 2.8 GHz Quad CoreIntel Core i7
- 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 1536 MB
- Docker: 19.03.12
- Druid: 0.19.0

Although I followed official instructions, I failed to build or run Druid locally.

### About this: https://github.com/apache/druid/tree/master/distribution/docker

I typed the following commands.

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/druid.git
docker build -t apache/druid:tag -f distribution/docker/Dockerfile .
```

However, the program never proceed.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  78.19MB
Step 1/18 : FROM maven:3-jdk-8-slim as builder
 ---> addee4586ff4
Step 2/18 : RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive     && apt-get -qq update     && apt-get -qq -y install --no-install-recommends python3 python3-yaml
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cdb74d0f6b3d
Step 3/18 : COPY . /src
 ---> 60d35cb6c0ce
Step 4/18 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in 73dfa666a186
Removing intermediate container 73dfa666a186
 ---> 4839bf923b21
Step 5/18 : RUN mvn -B -ff -q dependency:go-offline       install       -Pdist,bundle-contrib-exts       -Pskip-static-checks,skip-tests       -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
 ---> Running in 1c9d4aa3d4e8
```

### PLUS

Moreover, I followed this [instruction](https://github.com/apache/druid/tree/master/distribution/docker) and run `docker-compose -f distribution/docker/docker-compose.yml up` but I failed and get the error below.

```
coordinator      | 2020-08-06T08:41:24,295 WARN [Coordinator-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.server.coordinator.helper.DruidCoordinatorRuleRunner - Uh... I have no servers. Not assigning anything...
```

### PLUS END

### About this: https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/druid/tags

I typed the following commands.

```
docker pull apache/druid:0.19.0
docker run apache/druid:0.19.0
```

This program seems to work like this.

```
2020-08-06T07:50:22+0000 startup service 
Setting 172.17.0.2= in /runtime.properties
cat: can't open '/jvm.config': No such file or directory
2020-08-06T07:50:24,024 INFO [main] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.5.Final
2020-08-06T07:50:24,988 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.initialization.Initialization - Loading extension [druid-hdfs-storage], jars: jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar, hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.8.5.jar, httpclient-4.5.10.jar, htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar, apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar, commons-digester-1.8.jar, jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar, jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar, api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar, ion-java-1.0.2.jar, hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.8.5.jar, asm-7.1.jar, jsp-api-2.1.jar, druid-hdfs-storage-0.19.0.jar, api-util-1.0.3.jar, json-smart-2.3.jar, jackson-core-2.10.2.jar, hadoop-client-2.8.5.jar, httpcore-4.4.11.jar, commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, hadoop-hdfs-client-2.8.5.jar, hadoop-annotations-2.8.5.jar, hadoop-auth-2.8.5.jar, xmlenc-0.52.jar, aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.199.jar, commons-net-3.6.jar, nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar, hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar, jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.10.2.jar, hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.8.5.jar, accessors-smart-1.2.jar, gson-2.2.4.jar, commons-configuration-1.6.jar, joda-time-2.10.5.jar, hadoop-aws-2.8.5.jar, aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.199.jar, commons-codec-1.13.jar, hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.8.5.jar, hadoop-yarn-api-2.8.5.jar, aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.199.jar, jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar, curator-recipes-4.3.0.jar, hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.8.5.jar, jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar, jmespath-java-1.11.199.jar, hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.8.5.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar, curator-framework-4.3.0.jar, hadoop-yarn-client-2.8.5.jar, apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar
2020-08-06T07:50:25,004 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.initialization.Initialization - Loading extension [druid-kafka-indexing-service], jars: lz4-java-1.7.1.jar, kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar, druid-kafka-indexing-service-0.19.0.jar, zstd-jni-1.3.3-1.jar, snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar
2020-08-06T07:50:25,006 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.initialization.Initialization - Loading extension [druid-datasketches], jars: druid-datasketches-0.19.0.jar, commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
usage: druid <command> [<args>]

The most commonly used druid commands are:
    help       Display help information
    index      Run indexing for druid
    internal   Processes that Druid runs "internally", you should rarely use these directly
    server     Run one of the Druid server types.
    tools      Various tools for working with Druid
    version    Returns Druid version information

See 'druid help <command>' for more information on a specific command.
```

However, even if I add an argument like `version`, it does not work like this.

```
❯ docker run apache/druid:0.19.0 version
2020-08-06T07:51:30+0000 startup service version
Setting druid.host=172.17.0.2 in /runtime.properties
cat: can't open '/jvm.config': No such file or directory
2020-08-06T07:51:32,517 INFO [main] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.5.Final
2020-08-06T07:51:33,503 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.initialization.Initialization - Loading extension [druid-hdfs-storage], jars: jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar, hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.8.5.jar, httpclient-4.5.10.jar, htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar, apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar, commons-digester-1.8.jar, jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar, jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar, api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar, ion-java-1.0.2.jar, hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.8.5.jar, asm-7.1.jar, jsp-api-2.1.jar, druid-hdfs-storage-0.19.0.jar, api-util-1.0.3.jar, json-smart-2.3.jar, jackson-core-2.10.2.jar, hadoop-client-2.8.5.jar, httpcore-4.4.11.jar, commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, hadoop-hdfs-client-2.8.5.jar, hadoop-annotations-2.8.5.jar, hadoop-auth-2.8.5.jar, xmlenc-0.52.jar, aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.199.jar, commons-net-3.6.jar, nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar, hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar, jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.10.2.jar, hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.8.5.jar, accessors-smart-1.2.jar, gson-2.2.4.jar, commons-configuration-1.6.jar, joda-time-2.10.5.jar, hadoop-aws-2.8.5.jar, aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.199.jar, commons-codec-1.13.jar, hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.8.5.jar, hadoop-yarn-api-2.8.5.jar, aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.199.jar, jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar, curator-recipes-4.3.0.jar, hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.8.5.jar, jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar, jmespath-java-1.11.199.jar, hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.8.5.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar, curator-framework-4.3.0.jar, hadoop-yarn-client-2.8.5.jar, apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar
2020-08-06T07:51:33,524 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.initialization.Initialization - Loading extension [druid-kafka-indexing-service], jars: lz4-java-1.7.1.jar, kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar, druid-kafka-indexing-service-0.19.0.jar, zstd-jni-1.3.3-1.jar, snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar
2020-08-06T07:51:33,526 INFO [main] org.apache.druid.initialization.Initialization - Loading extension [druid-datasketches], jars: druid-datasketches-0.19.0.jar, commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
ERROR!!!!
Found unexpected parameters: [version]
===
usage: druid <command> [<args>]

The most commonly used druid commands are:
    help       Display help information
    index      Run indexing for druid
    internal   Processes that Druid runs "internally", you should rarely use these directly
    server     Run one of the Druid server types.
    tools      Various tools for working with Druid
    version    Returns Druid version information

See 'druid help <command>' for more information on a specific command
```

Answer (score 1):

So I see a few things here:

1. docker run apache/druid:0.19.0 means "fire and forget", if you don't have an endless running service here, your docker container will be shut down shortly after start.
   To have an interaction within the docker container start it with "-it" command.
   To let it run without interaction run it with "-d" command for detached.
   YOu can find information about this here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/
2. You have to check the start command.
   The thing you wrote after the run command is the start command (in your case "version") - this is runned like you would type it into the running shell after words (just "version").
   Additional to that, if you DONT add a startup command, there could be a startup command in the default druid dockerfile.
   You can see the dockerfile of your selected image at docker.hub, like here:

https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/druid/0.19.0/images/sha256-eb2a4852b4ad1d3ca86cbf4c9dc7ed9b73c767815f187eb238d2b80ca26dfd9a?context=explore

There you see, the start command, wihtin a dockerfile this is called ENTRYPOINT, is a shellscript:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/druid.sh"]
```

So writing "version" after your run commands stops the shell command from running - we should not do that :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I'd like to know what to type after all...

Comment: For that we must now more information what you want to reach. I would say start with the -it parameter to have an interactive docker and you can play around with Druid...

Comment: Do you mean that I should run `docker run -it apache/druid:0.19.0`?
I ran it, but somehow I get the same result.

Comment: I looked into it and it looks like Druid is simply missing the config file - see the error output. But then I stumbled upon this: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/docker.html, and there is explained how you set up Druid in Docker within a sample of a docker compose file in which the druid services are splitted up a lot with a bunch of information in the given envoriment-file. So I think you can't just download the single docker file and run it, becuase Druid needs a complete infrastructure to run!